# What configuration is needed to remove attachments from mails in Dovecot Sieve?

Tags: mail-server, dovecot, sieve

How can I remove specific attachments from mails in dovecot sieve mail server ?
I have tried several configurations but the attachments were not removed.
But it did not know keyword "replace" and I don't know what it requires.
I am using https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver.
Do I need a plugin or extenstion for doing that ?
Or what is the simplest configuration to do that ?

I tried
`replace :mime :contenttype "text/plain" "This email originally contained an attachment, which has been removed.";`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74918765/482519), you have to use sieve `extprograms` plugin to filter incoming messages.  Vanilla dovecot does not have specific sieve plugin to modify part of multipart MIME message.

First of all, you'll need to edit dovecot's `90-sieve.conf` to enable `+vnd.dovecot.filter`:

```
...
sieve_global_extensions = +vnd.dovecot.pipe +vnd.dovecot.filter
...
sieve_plugins = sieve_extprograms
...
```

Specify program location in `90-sieve-extprograms.conf`:

```
  sieve_pipe_bin_dir = /etc/dovecot/sieve-pipe
  sieve_filter_bin_dir = /etc/dovecot/sieve-filter
  sieve_execute_bin_dir = /etc/dovecot/sieve-execute
```

Create these directories:

```
mkdir -p /etc/dovecot/sieve-{pipe,filter,execute}
```

Then, write some filter program to strip attachments like following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from email.parser import Parser
from email.policy import default
from email.errors import MessageError

def main():
    parser = Parser(policy=default)
    stdin = sys.stdin

    try:
        msg = parser.parse(stdin)
        for part in msg.walk():
            if part.is_attachment():
                part.clear()
                part.set_content(
                    "This email originally contained an attachment, "
                    "which has been removed."
                )
    except (TypeError, MessageError):
        print(stdin.read())  # fallback
    else:
        print(msg.as_string())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Save this script as `/etc/dovecot/sieve-filter/strip_attachments.py` and make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/dovecot/sieve-filter/strip_attachments.py
```

Your sieve script should look like following:

```
require "mime";
require "vnd.dovecot.filter";

# Executing external programs is SLOW, should be avoided as much as possible.
if header :mime :anychild :param "filename" :matches "Content-Disposition" "*" {
    filter "strip_attachments.py";
}
```